Create a strapi project with npx with earlier version
In the strapi installation documentation this is the advised way to create a new strapi project:

npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project

# 'npx' runs a command from an npm package

# 'create-strapi-app' is the Strapi package

# '@latest' indicates that the latest version of Strapi is used

# 'my-project' is the name of your Strapi project


I've tried a few variations and searches to figure out how to create a strapi project with v4 of strapi but haven't figured it out. Can anyone help me with this?
I tried different variations of npx create-strapi-app@v4... with and without v and couldn't get a project created.

npx create-strapi-app@4 my-project would use v4 of create-strapi-app (currently 4.25.18) to create your project. What exactly is the problem with this?
